# Make a variable from COUNTA in table column

Tags: vba, counting, listobject

I want to perform the following:
'Count all non-blank cells in column 1 of the table on the active sheet.
'Save this number of cells as variable "TransQty".
'If count is 0, message "No projects on this tab are marked for transition".
'If count is greater than 0, yes/no message "'TransQty' projects will be transitioned from this tab.  Would you like to proceed?"
'If "no", end.
'If "yes", proceed with the rest of the code.

I would like to use the title of the table column, as opposed to the column position.  That way adding & removing columns will not impact the function of the code.

```
Sub Transition_from_Queue()

Dim TransRange As Range
Dim TransQty As Integer

Set TransRange = Worksheets("Project Queue").DateBodyRange("TableQueue[Transition]")

For Each TransRange In Selection
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(TransRange) Then
        TransQty = TransQty + 1
    End If
Next TransRange

If TransQty = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No projects on this tab are marked for transition."
        Else
        If TransQty > 0 Then
            MsgBox Range("TransQty") & "projects will be transitioned from this tab." & vbNewLine & "Would you like to continue?"
        End If
End If
```

I've found several problem after trying the code multiple different ways.
1) I am not identifying the table column correctly and cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.  I want to use the column title, not the column position.
2) Whether I have text in 0 cells or 100 cells of the target column, I keep receiving the message for TransQty = 0.

Comment: What is `DateBodyRange`? Looks like a typo, but more importantly `DataBodyRange` is a property of a `ListObject`, not a `Worksheet`.

Answer (score 0):

You're code is pretty close to what you need. There are two main points in my example below. The first is to assign your table column straight to a `Range`. The second point is how to check a cell to see if it's empty. Using `COUNTA` is fine to count the number of cells in a whole range that are empty, but doesn't work in (what I think) is the reason for your loop.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim thisSheet As Worksheet
    Set thisSheet = ActiveSheet

    '--- this is not really needed, but shows how to get a variable
    '    for the whole table
    Dim thisTable As ListObject
    Set thisTable = thisSheet.ListObjects("TableQueue")

    Dim transitionData As Range
    Set transitionData = thisSheet.Range("TableQueue[Transition]")

    '--- this gets you how many non-blank cells in the range
    Dim transQty As Long
    transQty = WorksheetFunction.CountA(transitionData)

    '--- BONUS CODE!!!!  totals up the non-blank data in the range
    '    (though not asked for by OP)
    Dim data As Range
    Dim transitionQty As Double
    For Each data In transitionData
        If Not IsEmpty(data.Value) Then
            transitionQty = transitionQty + data.Value
        End If
    Next data

End Sub
```

Comment: I reread the question. Am I right in understanding that OP is looking for a *count*, not a *sum*? Loop then is unnecessary, and a single `WorksheetFunction.CountA` line should do the trick, right?

Comment: Correct @BigBen I'm looking for a count.  The data in the cells is text selected from a data validation list.  I want to count how many cells have text in them.

Comment: After you've fixed the  `Set TransRange` line, `TransQty = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(TransRange)`.

Comment: My brain is moving slower than my fingers this morning. Thanks for straightening me out. Corrected code above

Comment: You could also use `WorksheetFunction.Sum` instead of a loop and checking for non-empty cells, but I digress...